# SqlParameter set value not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Could anybody help me to understand what I'm doing wrong in the below piece of code?:

```
//....


internal static string InsertCorrespondenceRecipientItem(TbEmail email, Guid correspondenceId, Guid contactId) => $@"
         INSERT INTO CorrespondenceRecipientItems
           (Id, DateSent, Subject, ToEmail, [CorrespondenceId] , [ToId], [CorrespondenceRecipientId])
         VALUES
             ('{email.Guid}', '{email.DateSent}', @subject, @emailString, '{correspondenceId}', '{contactId}', '{email.Guid}')
        ";
    var sqlItemsUpdate = SqlHelpers.InsertCorrespondenceRecipientItem(item.email, correspondence.Guid, fromId);
                                var subject = item.email.Subject.Trim();
                                var emailString = item.email.EmailAddressString.Trim();

                                await _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sqlItemsUpdate, new SqlParameter("@subject", subject), new SqlParameter("@emailString", emailString));
```

The result in the database is

```
'7F856136-0036-4F68-249F-08D5AB631656', @subject, @emailString
```

Why does the execution not set the value for the parameters?

Comment: your parameter is called emailString not @email

Comment: sorry, typing mistake, the parameter names are matching

Comment: What do you mean? it's sql parameter real values are not going to be in command text

Comment: @Hesam Yes, so I should see in the database  '7F856136-0036-4F68-249F-08D5AB631656', test, dot.dot@dot.com; I tried SqlParameter("@subject", subject).Value

Comment: If there is no exception, yes

Comment: The SQL Client library **DOES NOT** do a text-replace on the parameter values in your SQL statement - those parameters are sent to SQL Server **as such** - as parameters with names and datatypes - and their values are sent separately.

Comment: There is no exception, everything executes is just that the instance of the parameter is not evaluated with the initialized value

Comment: @marc_s Than the questions is, what I do in order to be replaced?

Comment: You **don't** do anything - this is the way it's designed to work, and it works just fine. Trying to do this would open the doors to **SQL injection** which you're trying to *avoid* by using parameters in the first place!

Comment: @marc_s: I don't follow your logic here. If the OP is seeing those values in the database, that's still a problem. If the OP were saying what they'd seen in a SQL profiler or similar, that's a different matter - but the way I understand the question is that the *values* in the database are the parameter names, when looking at the table data.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "The result in the database"? Are you looking at the logs of the SQL executed, or looking at the data in the table?

Comment: @Daisy I'm looking to the data in table

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. Unfortunately I don't know why this isn't working - it looks right to me :( Are you sure that's *exactly* your SQL? This would be explained if you had something like `"INSERT INTO Table(Id, Subject, Email) VALUES (NEWID(), '@subject', '@emailString')"` with the parameter names in quotes like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you need a working solution, instead of the reason, why the other one doesn’t work...:

```
//....
var subject= "test";
var emailString ="dot.dot@dot.com";
await _db.Database
        .ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"INSERT INTO Table(Id, Subject, Email) VALUES (NEWID(), {subject }, {emailString})");
```

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments, I‘ll have to explain that a interpolated string with parameter(s) like above, will be parametrized by EF-Core, if it’s declared inline.

The following statement is not parametrized and therefore indeed vulnerable to sql-injection:

```
//....
    var subject= "test";
    var emailString ="dot.dot@dot.com";
string sql= "INSERT INTO Table(Id, Subject, Email) VALUES (NEWID(), {subject }, {emailString})";
    await _db.Database
            .ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql);
```

To proof the information you can check in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: Unless there's a use of `FormattableString` that I'm not aware of here, this is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. If this *is* a use of `FormattableString` you should definitely explain that *very* carefully, to avoid people using this as a solution in cases where it isn't using parameters.

Comment: An interpolated string, which should be seen by the heading $ is in fact a FormattableString and isn’t vulnerable to Sql-injection. If you declare the string inline it’s parametrized by EF. This is readable in the docs.

Comment: Interpolated strings are only `FormattableString` when there's a parameter or assignment to it, which isn't at all clear as you haven't stated it or linked to the docs at all. "This is readable in the docs" isn't *nearly* clear enough IMO for a pretty fragile solution - anyone using this in a situation where the argument *isn't* converted into a `FormattableString` will be opening themselves up to a SQL injection attack by following your answer.

Comment: Additionally, I don't see that overload anywhere here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommandasync(v=vs.113).aspx - perhaps it's not in *all* versions of EF, but only EF Core? Again, without your answer giving any warning about this at all, I think it's doing more harm than good. With explanation and a warning to *only* use that when the interpolated string literal is converted to `FormattableString` rather than `string`, it would be a good answer - but not right now, IMO.

Comment: @Nikolaus This I used and works till to a point where the subject, and {email String} contains all sorts of characters which I had to escape and ended ugly, so I thought that would be better to use sql parameters

Comment: @Daniel.Cristian: If it's actually using `FormattableString`, you shouldn't need to escape anything - it would be using parameterized SQL behind the scenes. Are you definitely, definitely using EF Core? If you're using EF6 with one of the calls I showed earlier, that wouldn't be parameterizing it.

Comment: @Folks, Sorry, it seems that I'm just tired. is all fine, the posted version works and is doing what it is supposed to do. Thank you for your attention

Comment: @Daisy     <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />

Comment: @DaisyShipton It’s indeed only in EF-Core and I only see that Tag under the question. Maybe I should explain it better, which I will. But how can it be vulnerable to Sql-injection, if there is no parameter added?

Comment: @Nikolaus: It would be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks if the interpolated string literal were converted to a string instead of a `FormattableString`. So if someone tried to use this answer in a *very slightly* different context (e.g. EF rather than EF Core) they'd have problems - and because you hadn't explained how it works at all, there was no warning to anyone about how it could be dangerous. It's better now.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized queries:

query = INSERT INTO ReportingLogs ([UserName],[FirstName]) values (@username,@firstname)

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username

//Close the connection in finally block or use using() statement

Comment: The OP was already trying to use a parameterized query. We still don't know why it was working - it looks to me like it should have worked fine.